# Error:The following SimPowerSystem block is not allowed with the Phasor simulation method

Tags: matlab, simulink, mat, turbine, simpowersystems

I have download wind turbine project from math work. In generator block they used Asynchronous Machine SI Units. when i try to change Asynchronous Machine SI Units with Asynchronous Machine pu Units.

I got the following error:

**The following SimPowerSystem block is not allowed with the Phasor simulation method:
Block : Wind_Turbine/Nacelle/Generator/Full/Asynchronous Machine pu Units
Type : Asynchronous Machine Wound Rotor**

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can't use the pu units version of the asynchronous machine block with a phasor simulation. Either use SI units or change the simulation type to something else other than phasor.

I assume you are referring to the [Wind Turbine](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25752-wind-turbine-model) model on the File Exchange. You might have better luck either leaving a comment on the Wind Turbine page on the FEX, or asking [the author](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/29641).